# pyspark: change string to timestamp

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, type-conversion, sql-timestamp, to-timestamp

I've a column in String format , some rows are also null.
I add random timestamp to make it in the following form to convert it into timestamp.

| date |
| --- |
| null |
| 22-04-2020 |

| date |
| --- |
| 01-01-1990 23:59:59.000 |
| 22-04-2020 23:59:59.000 |

```
df = df.withColumn('date', F.concat (df.date, F.lit(" 23:59:59.000")))
df = df.withColumn('date', F.when(F.col('date').isNull(), '01-01-1990 23:59:59.000').otherwise(F.col('date')))

df.withColumn("date",      F.to_timestamp(F.col("date"),"MM-dd-yyyy HH mm ss SSS")).show(2)
```

but after this the column date becomes null.

can anyone help me solve this.
either convert the string to timestamp direct

Answer (score 0):

Your timestamp format should start with `dd-MM`, not `MM-dd`, and you're also missing some colons and dots in the time part. Try the code below:

```
df.withColumn("date", F.to_timestamp(F.col("date"),"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS")).show()
+-------------------+
|               date|
+-------------------+
|1990-01-01 23:59:59|
|2020-04-22 23:59:59|
+-------------------+
```